# Show formula which does not have quantifier elimination in theory of infinite equivalence relations.

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers

Let $T^-$ be theory which fulfills following axioms:

> (i) $\sim$ is an equivalence relation;
>   (ii) every equivalence class is infinite;

Find formula which is not $T^-$-equivalent to any formula without quantifiers.

I cannot work out such formula.

Comment: Do you know some different (= nonisomorphic) models of $T$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber you mean, for instance, models with diiferent amount of equivalence classes?

Comment: Yup. Now, can you think of a sentence which distinguishes (say) the one-class model from the two-class model?

Comment: @NoahSchweber as a matter of fact, I can.

Comment: Good, now presumably that sentence has quantifiers in it; can you show that it is not equivalent to a quantifier-free sentence? (HINT: it's enough to show that any two models of $T^-$ have the same parameter-free quantifier-free theory. What quantifier-free sentences does our language allow, here?)

Comment: By parameter-free you mean formulas without constants?

Comment: Yes, although I'd use the term "parameters" rather than "constants," to distinguish them from constants appearing in the actual language. Note, by the way, that it doesn't even make sense really to compare the theories, or quantifier-free theories, *with* parameters of two different structures!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature of $T^-$ which is quite useful here: it is *incomplete*. In a complete theory, every sentence is either provable from the theory or disprovable from the theory, hence equivalent (over the theory) to either $\top$ or $\perp$. Because of this, if you want to show that a certain complete theory does not have quantifier elimination, you need to work with formulas with free variables - this amounts to analyzing the definable sets of an arbitrary model, and can often be quite complicated.

With an incomplete theory, however, we have a potentially simpler (at least, intuitively simpler) opportunity: we can look for a *sentence* which is not equivalent (over the theory) to any quantifier-free *sentence*. Specifically, we'll be done if we can do the following two things:

- Show that any two models of our theory have the same **parameter-free** quantifier-free theory.
- Show that there are two models of our theory which are not elementarily equivalent.

Analyzing the parameter-free quantifier-free sentences is generally much easier than looking at arbitrary formulas with free variables. In particular, it's often the case - as it is here - that the language of the theory we're studying simply doesn't allow for many quantifier-free sentences:

> What are the quantifier-free sentences in the language of $T^-$? (There won't be very many, even if you allow "$\top$" and "$\perp$" as logical constants - which is a minor point of inconsistency between presentations of the subject.)

And the second bulletpoint is just the fact that our theory is incomplete, which in this case is easy:

> Two countable models of $T^-$ are determined entirely by the number of equivalence classes; conversely, any number (from $1$ to $\omega$) of equivalence classes is allowed by $T^-$. So can you find a sentence which distinguishes (say) the two-class model from the one-class model?

Comment: For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and given $x_1,\dots,x_n$ we can write formula $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ as $(\bigwedge_{i,i'\in I}\neg(x_i\sim x_{i'})\wedge\bigwedge_{j,j'\in J}x_j\sim x_{j'}\wedge\bigwedge_{h,h'\in H}x_h\neq x_{h'})$ for some $I,G,H\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$. Is it what we're looking for in first question?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk No, that would be how you prove that quantifier elimination **does** hold; this problem is to show that it doesn't. Besides, the whole point of my answer is that in this case we can simplify things by looking at **sentences** rather than arbitrary formulas.

Comment: Ok, I have some elementary problem here. To have sentence I have to make sure that there are no free variable inside formula. Usually it can be done by bounding free variable to quantifier or changing it into constant. How can we have sentence without parameters and quantifiers?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk It depends on the language. E.g. in the usual language of arithmetic $\{0,1, +,\times, <\}$, "$1+1<0$" is an example of a quantifier-free sentence. My *whole point* is that in this particular case, *there are very few quantifier-free sentences*; can you figure out what all of them are? Remember, having few quantifier-free sentences is **good** here: it makes it harder for a given sentence to be equivalent to a quantifier-free one, and we want to find a sentence which in fact **isn't** equivalent to any quantifier-free one. So we should be happy that there are very few of those.

Comment: So there are no quantifier-free parameter-free sentences in $T^-$?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk Well, there are the logical constants $\perp$ and $\top$ (falsity and truth, respectively) and their Boolean combinations. It varies from author to author whether these are part of the syntax of first-order logic , and most of the time it doesn't matter since "$\exists x(x\not=x)$" and "$\forall x(x=x)$" can be used in their steads, respectively. However, in the context of quantifier elimination it does matter, and they are often explicitly included here since they tend to make things more natural.

Comment: But yes, in this case there are no "nontrivial" quantifier-free sentences, so it's enough to show that $T^-$ is not a complete theory.

Comment: Quantifier-free formula is either true or false in specific model. Therefore it is equivalent to quantifier-free sentence (with proper truth-value) in that model. This is the reason why we can limit ourselves to consideration of sentences?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk "Quantifier-free formula is either true or false in specific model. Therefore it is equivalent to quantifier-free sentence (with proper truth-value) in that model." No. Is the formula "$x+1=1+1$" true or false in the standard model of arithmetic? The reason we can limit ourselves to a consideration only of sentences is because we're looking for a **counterexample** to something - so any formula will do as long as it isn't $T^-$-equivalent to any quantifier-free formula. Sentences are a particularly simple kind of formula, so it's reasonable to start there. (cont'd)

Comment: Of course, this would be a silly starting point *if our theory were complete*, since then any sentence is equivalent to either $\perp$ or $\top$ over that theory. But in this case we know our theory isn't complete - this was bullet point 2 - so it's a reasonable attempt. And the point is that it works. This was the focus of my first two paragraphs.